# Asking spreadtab to add all rows above?

Tags: tables, spreadtab, arithmetic

I love the idea behind spreadtab. The author should be congratulated.

However, it seems to require that I specify specific numbers for the rows that I want to add. What if I have a document, where I am adding more rows every now and then? Is it possible to have a syntax that takes the form 1:lastrow, with lastrow being calculated internally by the package and not me?

Comment: Some kind of a minimum working example would be nice.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the number of rows having to be specified?  (Or do you mean columns?)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{r}}
12       \\
13       \\
14       \\
\hline
sum(a1:[0,-1]) \\
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Please see the line with `sum(a1:[0,-1])`.  With `a1` is the first cell named (containing 12).  With `[0,-1]` you can address the cell before. If you are standing in cell `a4` (that is the cell were we want to calculate the sum) you call cell `a3` with `[0,-1]`.

Btw: with  `[0,-2]` you would call cell `a2` with the value `12`.

See the result of the given MWE (39 is calculated by function `sum`):

[image: result of the given MWE]

Btw2: Suppose you want to calculate the sum from cell `a1` until `d1` in cell `e1`. Then you can use `sum(a1:[-1,0])` in cell `e1`.

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `tag` macro and then write the `cell` macro in the argument of `sum`:

```
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{r}}
12            \\
13            \\% you can add rows
14tag(lastrow)\\\hline
sum(a1:cell(lastrow)) \\
\end{spreadtab}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example (using packages `longtable` and `spreadtab`) that has **zeroed out rows** at the beginning and at the end. These two rows are made invisible by `\phantom` and are moved up by `[-6.9mm]` at the begininng.

```
\begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{cccc}}%
@\textbf{ONE} & @\textbf{TWO} & @\textbf{THREE} & @\textbf{FOUR} \\
[-6.9mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(start)}} \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
[-6.9mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(stop)}} \\
@\textbf{vsota} & sum(cell(start):cell(stop))
\end{spreadtab}
```

This example alows you to **split the table** by defining two commands somewhere in the preamble of your document.

**First**:

```
\newcommand{\tablestart}{
    \begin{spreadtab}{{longtable}{cccc}}%
        @\textbf{dan} & @\textbf{ure} & @\textbf{vsebine} & @\textbf{status} \\
        [-6.9mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(start)}} \\

}
```

**Second**:

```
\newcommand{\tablestop}{
        [-6.9mm]\phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0}} & \phantom{:={0 tag(stop)}} \\
        @\textbf{vsota} & sum(cell(start):cell(stop))
    \end{spreadtab}
```

Then you also define **one more command** for users to be able to easily input data into table:

```
\newcommand{\input}[4]{
    #1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\
}
```

And then you can use these three commands in your document **in this order**:

```
\tablestart
\input{5}{6}{7}{8}
\input{5}{6}{7}{8}
\input{5}{6}{7}{8}
\tablestop
```

And table will sum it up!

---

### ERROR:

While this approach works if you don't split the table, it fails if you split it. Does anyone know why?